# How to enable glassy Aero theme in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Aero Glass/Transparent window borders in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/q/489853/138020)

How do I get the transparency Aero theme in Windows 8 like as in Windows 7? My graphics card driver is up to date but I dont see any "Aero" theme when I go to the Personalize menu.

Comment: Your question and tags are unclear. Do you want to enable transparency in Windows 7 or in Windows 8? Please consider editing your question and tags to make it clearer.

Comment: You can enable an alternate Aero implementation provided by Microsoft in the Windows 8 release called [**AeroLite**](http://superuser.com/a/493344/138020), but it does not bring back the old Aero Glass.

Comment: Is it the RTM or final realease?

Comment: Its what the average joe can buy in stores now.

Comment: [Check this][1]. Haven't personally tried it, so be careful.


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/459958/transparency-option-gone-from-windows-8

Comment: @PeterO. in comments if you want to format the link then type like this [link description](link) and you will get only the link description with link :)

Comment: Well, I was posting an answer, but it has ended here as a comment :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get transparency on title bars in Windows 8, like Aero of Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/493850/is-it-possible-to-get-transparency-on-title-bars-in-windows-8-like-aero-of-wind) and [Is there a way to make windows borders transparent?](http://superuser.com/questions/489853/is-there-a-way-to-make-windows-borders-transparent).

Answer (score 4):

Aero has been removed in Windows 8. Microsoft states it is because transparency is no longer cool and Metro is all about simple shapes and clear colours. But I guess the decision was made to not have a shader running all the time just for that bit of transparency effect as it tends to drain the battery faster.

Comment: It was removed because of battery issues.

Comment: I know (and something got lost in the rewrite, sorry), but that's not what MS's marketing told us :P

Comment: @Joey "but that's not what MS's marketing told us"  they are all liars in Marketing, you did not know this? :-)

Comment: I did, hence the last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Aero8Tuner](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.95). It lets you get transparency but it is not so usable.

[image: Aero8Tuner]

Comment: Is this like the **Aero of Windows 7**?

Comment: I don't see any transparency there (only horrible JPEG artifacts)

Comment: Not so much. But it lets you get transparency.

Answer (score 0):

However MS removed the feature of Aero in Windows 8 but you can still enable it by tweak in Windows 8 RTM. Before we proceed

**Note**: Please create a restore point or a backup of registry in any kind of buggy situation.

Press the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type

> regedit

now navigate to the following key path

> Computer/HKEY_CURRENT_USER/software/Microsoft/Windows/DWM

Now select the key `ColorizationGlassAttribute` and double click on it. Now change the value from `1` to `2`. Close the registry editor.

Now open the task manager and under `Processes` tab find the `Windows Processes` and select the `Desktop Windows Manger` and click on `End Task`.

[image]

Now a popup dialog will appear then mark the option `Abandon unsaved data and shut down` and click OK.

[image]

Congrats you have aero effect on your system now. But carefully it is buggy ao use it at your own risk.

Source is this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWt94nGwzZ4)

Comment: So it works only in Win8 RTM, but not in other Win 8 versions?